# How can I pass the json object using button with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, onclick

I have a simple json javascript obj. I am trying to pass the object with onclick button to process function and display contents in console.log

I have tried sending as js object and also as JSON.stringify... both are having issues... ex:  undefined Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Q: how can I pass the json using onclick to the process function and successfully  display its contents.

```
<script>

//set json obj

var obj = {  
        "first":       "joe", 
        "last":       "smith",   
        "cell":       "213 111 2222"
};

var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(obj);

</script>


<script>

// various button tries

output = "";


output += "<div >" + 

"<button class=\"buttonform2_16_small\" onclick=\"process(" + obj + ")\">obj </button>"
+
"<button class=\"buttonform2_16_small\" onclick=\"process('" + obj + "')\">obj 2 w q</button>"
+
"<button class=\"buttonform2_16_small\" onclick=\"process(" + jsonstr + ")\">jsonstr </button>"
+
"<button class=\"buttonform2_16_small\" onclick=\"process('" + jsonstr + "')\">jsonstr w q </button>"
+
"<button class=\"buttonform2_16_small\" onclick=\"process('" + txtstr + "')\">text w quote </button>"
+ "<br>"
+ "</div>"; 

$('#list').html( output );


</script>


<script id="scr process"> 

//process 

function process(item) {

    console.log('item is : ' + item);

    console.log('item first name is : ' + item.first);

    var res = JSON.parse(item);

    console.log('res  is : ' + res);
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `addEventListener`?

Comment: Since JSON uses double quotes around strings, you have to use single quotes around the `onclick=` value.

Comment: Thanks much for the help - Barmar - you may notice that in the 2nd try I did enclose in single quotes ```"<button class=\"buttonform2_16_small\" onclick=\"process('" + obj + "')\">obj 2 w q</button>"``` is that not correct?

Comment: Thanks IT Goldman I will try your example

Answer (score 0):

You should escape it, i.e mainly replace `"` with `&quot;`

```js
function esc_attr(string) {
  if (!string) {
    return "";
  }
  return ("" + string).replace(/[&<>"'\/\\]/g, function(s) {
    return {
      "&": "&amp;",
      "<": "&lt;",
      ">": "&gt;",
      '"': '&quot;',
      "'": '&#39;',
      "/": '&#47;',
      "\\": '&#92;'
    }[s];
  });
}

var obj = {
  something: {
    another: 12,
    arr: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    evil: "don't &j39'\!$K!d1//93^%^do <scri" + "pt>alert(12)</sc" + "ript>"
  },
  bool: false
}

var button = "<button onclick='console.log(" + esc_attr(JSON.stringify(obj)) + ")'>click me</button>"
document.body.innerHTML = button;
```

Comment: The only character you actually need to escape is `'`, so it won't match the `'` in `onclick='`

Comment: What do you mean? the function escapes also `'`

Comment: Right. You don't need to escape the rest. They have no special meaning inside a quoted attribute value.

Comment: It is more of a a general utility function I use to escape html or attributes everywhere.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Now things are working well!